# How to set up VPN on a new Fedora 16 install?

Tags: linux, vpn, fedora, networkmanager, selinux

I have a new Fedora 16 install with Gnome and want to use VPN. The instructions at Riseup.net say if the certificate is not read because SEinux is enabled then I need to put my riseup.pem in `~/.cert`. Below is from their troubleshoot page:

> If you are on a distribution that has SELinux enabled (eg. Fedora), then SELinux is going to block OpenVPN from accessing cert files unless they have specific permissions set properly. You need to put the Riseup cert into ~/.cert and then you need to run:
>
> `restorecon -Rv ~/.cert`

I have created a file named `.cert` in my home directory and run restore but to no avail. Can someone give me clear instructions? Was it a file I was supposed to create?

I have little grasp of what it is I need to do here. I use Mint and used this same VPN with no trouble and this is Fedora for an old laptop. From what I've read it seems others have this same problem with Fedora/SELinux but I guess I do not understand the solution.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're supposed to make a *directory* named `~/.cert` and then copy the `riseup.pem` into that directory.

Comment: @Micheal Hampton I am unsure how to do that, I think I do that in my terminal?   Like mk dir ....  Thanks , I will query how to do this

Comment: @soupy You can use the `mkdir` command.

Comment: Found tutorial for this http://beginnerlinuxtutorial.com/help-tutorial/basic-linux-commands/mkdir-how-to-create-a-directory-in-linux/  Thanks